# Wrong display of virtual camera in nested swf, flash action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, camera, nested, virtual

Im prity new in flash.
I have a virtual camera which zoom a square by these comands, (i got from internet).

```
parent.scaleX = 1 / scaleX;
parent.scaleY = 1 / scaleY;
parent.x = (width / 2 - x) / scaleX;
parent.y = (height / 2 - y) / scaleY;
```

It is inside a swf file, which will be displayed inside another flash file by using child movieclip as, inside a loader.
But the "parent" command in this nested swf cause it to display the square are to the whole area of main swf file, i want to make the nested swf file work seperatly inside parent swf file display virtual camer, not affect whol file.
Please hellp
Thank you

Comment: I realized, the parent swf display full nested swf file, how to display the viable square area of nested swf not full file objects.

Comment: After two week i found the anser in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679505/as3-hide-elements-outside-the-stage-in-loaded-swf